# How can I fix this ES6 promise chain in Express?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm starting with Promise chaining and I'm trying some code using express and mongoose in node. This is my code:

```
const register = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne(req.params.email).exec().then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(409).json({ error: 409 });
    }
    return User.create(req.body);
  }).then(user => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ sub: user._id }, 'test-secret');
    return res.status(200).json({ token });
  }).catch(err => {
    return next(err);
  });
};
```

This is a simplified code to register a user and send him a token. What I want to do is, first, check if the user is already registered and, if not, register it.

As you can see, the line 6 is wrong I think, because I'm not returning any Promise, so after the line 4, the code continuos executing. I want to avoid the callback hell, how can I accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you're not returning a `Promise` is not important. Return values from `then()` and `catch()` are automatically wrapped in `Promise` objects.

The problem is that your flow is linear (it follows a straight path), but you are trying to branch so that some parts only run in some cases. You need two execution paths:

```
const register = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne(req.params.email).exec().then(user => {
    if (user) {
      // Path 1 stops here:
      return res.status(409).json({ error: 409 });

    } else {
      // Path 2 continues down this 2nd Promise chain:
      return User.create(req.body).then(user => {
        const token = jwt.sign({ sub: user._id }, 'test-secret');
        return res.status(200).json({ token });
      })
    }

  }).catch(err => {
    // Both paths converge on this error handler
    return next(err);
  });
};
```

If you want to avoid deep nesting, you have two options:

1. Encapsulate the different paths into functions, so you can then do something like this:

   ```
   if (user) {
     return sendHttpError(res, 409)
   } else {
     return sendNewUser(res, req.body)
   }
   ```

Perhaps only the `sendHttpError` function is necessary, and the other possible path can be the main body of your route. This is pretty standard.

2. Since one of your branches is only dealing with error cases, you can throw an `Error` and catch it below, or in an error-handling middleware. It would look like this:

   ```
   if (user) {
     // This throw will abort execution of everything that follows. By
     // using a custom Error class, you can then handle it appropriately
     // in a catch() handler or Express middleware:
     throw new APIError(409)
   }

   // ... create user and proceed normally
   ```

This is also a very common pattern.

Comment: So, it's not possible to have a Promise chain here right?

Comment: You need a forking chain, logically, but not necessarily nested in the written text of the code. I added two possible strategies for avoiding nesting callbacks to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just throw an `error` if the user already exists to go directly to the `catch` function.

```
const register = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne(req.params.email).exec().then(user => {
    if (user) {
      throw new Error({ error: 409, msg: 'User already exists' });
    }
    return User.create(req.body);
  }).then(user => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ sub: user._id }, 'test-secret');
    return res.status(200).json({ token });
  }).catch(err => {
    return next(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes, that's a possible answer, but I forgot to say that I'm using the catch blocks to catch runtime errors only

Comment: You can specify the error to throw so it's easy to differentiate runtime errors from yours.
`throw new Error({ foo: 'bar', ...});`
`catch(err => { 
    if (err.foo === 'bar') {
        // this is your error
    } else {
        // runtime error
    }
})`